# Jetty 9 failed to start in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: jetty, ubuntu-12.04

I had installed Jetty 9.1.2 in ubuntu 12.04. But it fails to start.

```
$ sudo service jetty start
Starting Jetty: FAILED Thu Apr 10 11:28:43 IST 2014
```

I feel the error should be in `jetty.sh` file in `/ete/iniit.d`. Do let me know how to start the jetty server.

Even `java -jar start.jar` doesn't works.

Comment: I think a better place to ask is http://askubuntu.com